# Port 443 is open but IP tables denies it

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, firewall, nmap

When I run the following command on my Ubuntu instance:

`$ nmap host`

I see that port 443 is open:

```
Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-03-19 05:36 PDT
Nmap scan report for [host redacted] (ip address redacted)
Host is up (0.000034s latency).
rDNS record for [ip address redacted]: [host redacted]
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
21/tcp    open  ftp
25/tcp    open  smtp
80/tcp    open  http
443/tcp   open  https
30000/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.13 seconds
```

However, I'm not able to telnet to port 443. When I do so, I see the following entry in my syslog

```
Mar 19 05:39:30 localhost kernel: iptables denied: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=f2:3c:91:ae:c6:7a:c8:4c:75:f5:d6:3f:08:00 SRC=(ip address redacted) DST=(ip address redacted) LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=52 ID=23782 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=53375 DPT=443 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

And the output of `iptables -L --line-numbers` ACCEPT chain:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
2    REJECT     all  --  anywhere             127.0.0.0/8         reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
3    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
4    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www 
5    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:30000 
6    LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix `iptables denied: ' 
7    REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
8    ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
9    ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
10   ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
11   ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
12   ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
13   ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
14   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https
```

I once tried to use UFW, but now that's disabled and I'm just using iptables. I see that on line 14 I'm accepting packets to port 443, but on line 7 I'm rejecting packets. Is the problem with the positioning of the rule? If so, how can I move it further up the chain? Or is it a problem with the rule itself?

When I view the bash history, I believe this was the rule used:

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT`

UPDATE:

I just solved this by moving the rule further up the chain, and deleting the rule that was appended:

```
$ iptables -I INPUT 6 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT # add the rule to the 6th position
$ iptables -L
$ iptables -D INPUT 15 # delete line 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Your rules need to go before the reject line and log line

```
6    LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix `iptables denied: ' 
7    REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Should be last. This is because the rules are processed in order and the once it gets a match it doesn't look at any more rules